# RowEditing in GridView is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to change a record mode in a GridView to "Edit-Mode" i.e., when user clicks on Edit button in GridView to edit a specific record.

I using the following code:

```
                protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True");

        string sql = "select [DwgRegID],[Ref],[Dwg_Ref],[Title],[Dwg_Received_Date],[Rev],[Trade],[Type],[Produced_Date],[Produced_By],[Submittal_Ref],[Issued_To],[Date_Issued],[Purpose],[Status],[Action_Date] from dbo.Dwg_Register where [DwgRegID]=N'" + GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text + "'";
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

But its not working. Program is simply throwing me out EDITRECORD View to home-View.

Gridview structure (.aspx) is as followed:

GridView Structure part is:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="DwgRegID" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Kindly help.

Regards

Comment: _"EDITRECORD View to home-View"_ What does that mean?

Comment: please post gridview structure (aspx part)

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I have 2 Views ( ViewHome, ViewGrid ). 

home-View contains buttons with different options like 'insert a record', 'edit a record', 'update a record' ect. 

ViewGrid has the GridView on it. so when the user clicks 'Edit a Record' on 'Home-View', programs takes user to 'ViewGrid). 

Hope you get it.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam:  Gridview structure part is too long to be pasted here .. any alternate way to paste it?

Comment: Hey, i think you are not providing the data source,

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I have edit my question. Please view Gridview structure there. Thank you.

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam : I have edit my question again. Followed what I understood from your code. Please review. Thank you

Comment: please write binding data once outside, and you don't need to write again in row editing , such as i have function private void databind() { sql data source  }  , then again call this function row editing like GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; databind(),

Comment: bind with same datasource, i row_editing that you have bind at first

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
///////////GridView1.Datasource = datasource;  // here you missing
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the EditIndex property to the appropriate row and then Re-Bind the GridView again to it's DataSource.

here is the code

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
   {
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();

   }
```

You can read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/260328/The-GridView-GridView1-fired-event-RowEditing-whic)

Comment: Can you please go through my code and tell where I am going wrong? Because I cant _understand_ your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @ Microtechie: Your solution is giving this following error: 

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Please check , i have modified my answer..Try and let me know

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        DataBind();
    }
```